# Salvar uma página a partir de um HTMLPage (java)

Tags: java, html

Tenho um método que gera um HtmlPage, gostaria de salvar em disco.

```
public void gerarPaginaIndex() {
    try {
        final HtmlPage paginaIndex = WebClientFactory.getInstance().getPage(URL_INICIAL);
        this.criarPaginaEmDisco(paginaIndex, new File(PATH + "paginaIndex.html"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

O método criarPaginaEmDisco () recebe por parametro o endereço pra salvar e o HtmlPage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O modo mais simples de salvar uma arquivo usando `Java 8` é o seguinte:

```
Files.write(Paths.get(PATH + "paginaIndex.html"), paginaIndex.asXml().toString().getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO‌​-8859-1")));
```

Comment: Testei aqui e quando fui abrir o arquivo, não me retornou o site em si, dei um inspecionar e no body estava apenas HtmlPage e a url. Tentei assim: Files.write(Paths.get(PATH + "paginaIndex.html"), paginaIndex.asXml().toString().getBytes());  Deu certo, PORÉM veio com uns caracteres especiais. ps.: desculpem alguma coisa, estou aprendendo sobre ainda.

Comment: @Laryssa bem vinda ao Stack Overflow. Você pode especificar o que seriam os caracteres especiais?

Comment: Exemplos: InformaÃ§Ãµes Gerais ... Â Â aoÂ Â Â Â Â Â

Comment: Consegui salvar a página, mas algumas palavras com acentuação ou não, veio com caracteres desse tipo acima.

Comment: @Laryssa fiz uma pequena alteração no código que deve cobrir a acentuação. Verifique por favor

Comment: Obrigada @Sorack , mas não deu certo. Ainda com os caracteres

Comment: @Laryssa fiz mais uma alteração. Por favor verifique

Comment: Apareceu isso e ficou em vermelho: Unknown encoding: 'ISO 8859-1'.

Comment: @Laryssa estava faltando um traço. Corrigi a resposta

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigada! Só é necessario o asXml(), pra complementar:  Files.write(Paths.get(PATH + "paginaIndex.html"), paginaIndex.asXml().toString().getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")));

Answer (score 1):

A classe HtmlPage tem o método [*save*](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlPage.html#save-java.io.File-) que você pode utilizar nessa situação:

```
public void gerarPaginaIndex() {
try {
    final HtmlPage paginaIndex = WebClientFactory.getInstance().getPage(URL_INICIAL);
    //Salva a página
    paginaIndex.save(new File(PATH + "paginaIndex.html"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Caso você queira utilizar o método *criaPaginaEmDisco* é só encapsular a chamada para o *save*

```
public void criaPaginaEmDisco(HtmlPage pagina, File arquivo) throws IOException {
    pagina.save(arquivo);
}
```

Comment: Que bacana! Mas há um modo de não salvar imagens e os outros arquivos?

Comment: Para salvar apenas o html é melhor salvar no arquivo o retorno do _.toString()_, ou os bytes do html, como foi comentado abaixo.